# Ubuntu secure boot installation problems

Tags: boot, drivers, system-installation, uefi, secure-boot

I've installed ubuntu 22.04 on my old laptop. Since there was secure boot enabled, in the installation I checked the "Install third-party software and drivers" and entered the password in the "configure secure boot" field. After the installation was done, I rebooted and was entered with MOK blue menu. Without knowing what's going on I pressed "continue boot" and entered Ubuntu and nothing happened. After reading a little I understood that I didn't verify my key so third party drivers might not have been installed. 
So I wanted to try to enter that blue menu again, but couldn't. I tried to do it via UEFI,there's no schim option as it was suggesting in one answer. I checked available drivers, it says no available drivers in "additional drivers" app. I checked secure boot state, it says it's enabled. I've run `sudo mokutil --list-enrolled` it says there's one certificate of Canonical. I've tried to run `mokutil --enable-validation` but after entering password it says `Failed to request new MokSB state`. 
So what do I do in this situation? What's the correct way for me to enroll my key and to install third party drivers that should've been installed after the installation? 
UPD: Screw it, turned off secure boot and completely reinstalled ubuntu